# slack api invalid auth error building slack bot

Tags: python-3.x, slack, slack-api

I'm trying to write a python script that helps me automate my agile environment but every time I try to run the code I get this error.
"
slack_sdk.errors.SlackApiError: The request to the Slack API failed.
The server responded with: {'ok': False, 'error': 'invalid_auth'}
"
this is my code

```
import slack
import os
from pathlib import Path
from dotenv import load_dotenv


env_path = Path('D:\Work\FinHive\Mini Youssef')/ 'Env.env'
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=env_path)
client = slack.WebClient(token=os.environ['SLACK_TOKEN'])

client.chat_postMessage(channel='#test', text="this works")
```

Comment: Slack allow to set [IP restrictions](https://api.slack.com/authentication/best-practices#ip_allowlisting) to Slack bots. That may be a reason. I've got same error after bot's client global IP was changed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you already have set up a token for your application, but double check that the value in the environment variable matches what you have in your slack application.

If the value matches, then the next culprit would be permission for your bot to post on the channel. You can see in the API documentation for [postMessage](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage) that your bot needs the [chat:write](https://api.slack.com/scopes/chat:write) scope from your App page -> OAuth & Permissions -> Scroll down to scopes.

Finaly, make sure that the bot user is in the #test channel. You may need to grant your bot the channels:join scope, and invite them to #test.

Comment: thanks, but I've already checked multiple times that the bot has all the permissions and scopes it needed and that the value in the environment variable matches what I have in your slack application.
That's what's driving me crazy
Everything is in place so I don't really understand why it is showing me this error.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create your bot as new app or classic app?
Which token (xoxb-* or xoxp-*) are you using in your app?
I would suggest to validate your token https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage/test.

Answer (score 0):

Even when your token is valid/correct, Slack returns `invalid_auth` if you've set up Allowed IP Address Ranges and the request is originating from a non-allowed IP address. So you may need to simply adjust your Allowed IP Address Ranges. (IMO, the `invalid_auth` response in this case is confusing/misleading, but that's the way it is.)

See Slack docs here: https://api.slack.com/authentication/best-practices#ip_allowlisting